# Adding blank Data to an HTML Tag

Tags: jquery, html

I am wanting to get this result from adding a data attribute through jQuery.

```
<li class="uk-pearent" data-uk-dropdown="">
```

The code I am currently using is

```
$('.uk-pearent').data('data-uk-dropdown');
```

This just returns the data attribute which I have not assigned yet; so my Question is, how do I assign a blank data attribute to a html tag using jQuery.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> how do I assign a blank data attribute to a html tag using jQuery.

You can pass the value of data attribute as second argument of [data()](http://api.jquery.com/data/#data1)

```
$('.uk-pearent').data('uk-dropdown', '');
```

To get the value of data you have to remove data- before the key

```
var uk-dropdown = $('.uk-pearent').data('uk-dropdown');'
```

Syntax [.data( key, value )](http://api.jquery.com/data/#data1)

Comment: you can also use `attr` too right? is there any difference between the use of `attr` and `data`?

Comment: @DevZer0 `attr` is added to the DOM, `data` is not

Comment: I found using .attr worked whereas .data did not. I didnt want to assign it a value at all so i guess thats why .attr worked.

Comment: @George Shikari Reason, there was a typo, check updated answer, use $('.uk-pearent').data('data-uk-dropdown', '');